# Process killed while computing cosine similarity for large matrices

Tags: python, matrix, process, tensor, cosine-similarity

```
# A: 14287 * 768 array, B: 863394 * 768 array
def cosine_similarity(A,B):
    A = torch.tensor(A).to('cpu') ; B = torch.tensor(B).to('cpu')
    num = torch.mm(A, B.T)
    p1 = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(A**2, axis=1))[:, None]
    p2 = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(B**2, axis=1))[None, :]
    return (num/(p1*p2)).T
```

The process gets killed when I do cosine similarity for the two matrices.
I get the following logs on the machine:

```
[Apr 5 14:38] python invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100dca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[  +0.000003]  oom_kill_process+0xe6/0x120
[  +0.000001] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice,task=python,pid=8103,uid=1000
[  +0.000013] Out of memory: Killed process 8103 (python) total-vm:81517744kB, anon-rss:61879912kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:154388kB oom_score_adj:0
```

If I use `np.array` instead of `torch.tensor`, I still get OOM error as below:

```
  File "cosine.py", line 11, in cosine_similarity
    num=np.dot(A,B.T)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in dot
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 91.9 GiB for an array with shape (14287, 863394) and data type float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) library which reduces the time remarkably by using its efficient search algorithm and by utilizing the GPUs. Seemingly a 2-day job of computing cosine similarity finished in less than an hour.

Answer (score 0):

That's the [Linux oom (out of memory) killer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short/136294#136294), which selects processes to kill when available memory gets critically low.   You may be able to avoid it by either adding RAM or swap space, or restructuring your calculation to work on smaller chunks of data.

Comment: Can you give some pointers how to do it? I have no idea about how to add RAM or swap space or using smaller chunks?